# How do I edit the side-bar (doesn't seem to be a menu)?

Tags: sidebar

[image]

I need to edit this part of a website (highlighted in red). I am fairly new to WordPress so I'm not quite sure where to change this. I've gone into the widgets and the side menu however the only thing that shows is the php for the donate button.

I only need to edit the side bar highlighted in red, which seems separate from the "side bar" below it. The only side menu listed in widgets is the one with the Donate link.

Thanks.

Comment: See `sidebar.php` inside your theme directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please also check the sidebar.php as well the header.php file in the theme root directory.

On first sight it seems that its a header section which also includes the vertical menu.